# How to get websites logos with google sheets IMPORTXML with //img/@src?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet list with different companies and their website addresses. I am building a small app in glide and would like to include the companies logo. In my google sheet I want to have a URL to the logo image. Is there any way how I can filter out the other images, that I am getting with //img/@src? Please help me find the function for =importxml(E3,"//img/@src") -->get only logo.
Thank you for your help
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFVmN.png)

Comment: there is no general solution for this. for each url it would be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, you can use

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.xolo.io/zz-en","//link[@type='image/png']/@href")
```

No possibility for https://1office.co/ (the website uses javascript)

Third one

```
=importxml("https://www.firma.de/","//meta[@property='og:image']/@content")
```

you have to retrieve the specific xpath for each url

Comment: Thank you Mike. Seems like finding the URLs manually will be easier then.